# Isn't a permutation just a specific type of Mapping/Function?

Tags: group-theory, functions

Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph Gallian defines a permutation as

> A permutation of a set A is a function from A to A that is both one-to-one and onto.

This sound like a mapping or a function - a mapping or a function which is both one-to-one & onto.

However, composition order seems to be defined differently for both

---

1. 

[image: From "Topics in Algebra" by Hernstein]

Composition order for mappings seems to be left to right.

---

2. 

[image: From Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian]

Composition order seems to be right to left

---

So

- Are the two authors using different notations for the same thing

or

- Permutations are not a kind of mapping - ergo both have different notations?

or

- Permutations are a kind of mapping - but they still have different notations?

Comment: Yes. The authors just take the conventions that permutations act "from the right", and not "from the left", which means that composition should be done "from the right" and not "from the left" to conform with that. It is unfortunate, but it happens.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you - So Permutations are a kind of mapping - but they still have different notational convention?

Comment: Every bijective map can be understood as a permutation.  Different notations may be used, in order to define the group of permutations in a more natural way for the author.

Comment: Permutations are not just a "kind of" mapping, they *are* a mapping. The notational convention of that book is indeed different, nonetheless every individual permutation is a function (as is clear from the wording of the definition).

Comment: @AsafKaragila In some cases, including this one, notational inconsistencies are inevitable, so I would not describe them as unfortunate. In some more advanced contexts, such tensor products over non-commutative rings, you need both left and right actions as part of the same construction. But I would regard irritating inconsistencies about whether $0 \in {\mathbb N}$, for example, as unfortunate!

Comment: @Derek: Oh, absolutely. But inevitable things can be unfortunate as well. Life is full of examples...

Comment: @LeeMosher - which book's notational convention is different? What is the right notation? And it right for all mappings including permutations?

Comment: @Zanzag - so there is no one right way? One can use left to right for both permutations & mappings?

Comment: @user93353 You seem to keep repeating the same question. As Lee Mosher said, permutations are mappings, so anything that applies to mappings applies to permutations as well. There is no right answer to your question.

Comment: @user93353 There is no "right" notation. Each of the notations has its own advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem that arises from 2 issues: *notation abuse* and the *equivalence of left and right [**group actions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action)*. Understanding the notion of group action is key to understanding this matter. I encourage you to read and understand it carefully.

Permutations are, indeed, mappings that are onto and one-to-one.
$(\Sigma_n, \circ)$ is a group, where $\Sigma$ is a set of permutations on a set $X$ of $n$ elements. $\sigma\circ\tau$ means first applying $\tau$ and then $\sigma$, the usual definition of map composition.

We then define the natural group action on $X$ using $\Sigma_n$: the pair $(\sigma, x)$ or $(x, \sigma)$ (depends on whether the action is left or right) maps to $\sigma(x)$, where $\sigma\in\Sigma_n$ and $x\in X$.
However, it is frequent to denote the group action by $\circ$ to both the left and right group actions of $\Sigma_n$ on $X$. Thus, this is a notation abuse, we are denoting $\circ$ to two different things: one for the permutation composition and another for the group action.

To add to the matter, one can prove that every left group action is also a right group action and vice versa. So there is no solid argument to state which one is the "right" (pun intended) choice.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, mark it as the best one so that we can close this post.